# Use autoencoders on unlabeled data and reuse the weights for training labeled data

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a situation where I have a small number of labeled examples and a large number of unlabeled examples.

I am using an autoencoder model to train the unlabeled examples.

Now I want to train the encoder with labels. My doubt here is, by compiling the encoder model, am I creating a new model and not reusing the weights of the autoencoder?

Is the Encoder model a separate CNN model or is it still part of autoencoder?

```
x = Input(shape=(input_dim,))

encoder = Dense(output_dim)(x)

decoder = Dense(input_dim)(encoder)

autoencoder = Model(input=x, output=decoder)

out=dense(10,activation='softmax')(encoder)

supervised = Model(input=x, output=out)

autoencoder.compile(...)

supervised.compile(...)

autoencoder.fit(x1,x1)

supervised.fit(x2,y2)

supervised.predict(x3)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If by encoder part of autoencoder, you mean they share layers?

**Yes**, they do. However they can be differently compiled. This means you can have different optimisers, loss functions, etc. for them.

A simple way to check this is just predicting before and after training of a specific model like

```
x = Input(shape=(input_dim,))

encoder = Dense(output_dim)(x)

decoder = Dense(input_dim)(encoder)

autoencoder = Model(input=x, output=decoder)

out=dense(10,activation='softmax')(encoder)

supervised = Model(input=x, output=out)

autoencoder.compile(...)

supervised.compile(...)

weights_before = supervised.layers[1].get_weights()

autoencoder.fit(x1,x1)

weights_after = supervised.layers[1].get_weights()

print(weights_before, weights_after)

supervised.fit(x2,y2)

supervised.predict(x3)
```

You'll find the weights to be different while not training on supervised at all. This is because the Dense layer which outputs encodings is shared by both the models. Keep in mind, the models however are **different objects** with shared layers.